# Relating a product with attribute which has numerious options

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

**Scenario**

The site i am working on sells universities/institutes/school graduation growns. Insitially i was thinking about associating all institutes as options of an attribute but, what i am come to know now is they have 8K institutes to relate.

**Problem**

I have around 3K plus SKUs and 8K institutes to related with those. I can't think of solution with regular attribute and institutes as options to choose.

In these situations how do we manage in magento ? My question doesn't contain the programming part but it's kinda serious issue when one confronts, so i guess it's right to ask here..

Answer (score 1):

The following article might not be the exact solution logic but would be helpful to use.

http://blog.belvg.com/attribute-admin-page-pagination-in-magento.html

It describes about adding pagination to attribute options page in admin. It helps in solving the admin attribute page load issue when there are very large number of attribute options.

Comment: But there are around 8K options, is there any other work around for this to relate with products ? i mean to say, rather than placing all those options inside an attribute, if there is some work around way, like outside and could related to product... how about that ?

Comment: @K.C. You can add product sku and the options in a separate table (can be with sku and option fields) and then in frontend you can check that table and apply required logics.